# Batch script using msiexec can't find relative file to run

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I have a batch script inside a folder alongside a .msi file which I want it to run, however both these lines:

```
msiexec.exe /i /L*V "%~dp0\UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi"
msiexec.exe /i /L*V "%~dp0UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi"
```

return this error:

> This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package
>   exists...

The batch script and .msi are both inside C:\Users\jm_ta\Documents\test\ and `Echo %~dp0` does print out that filepath exactly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: echo "%~dp0\UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi" return what ? and this echo "%~dp0UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi" ?

Comment: I'd add `dir /A "%~dp0UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi"` and `dir "%~dp0UE4PrereqSetup_x86.msi"` to your script and check whether that `msi` exist (`dir /A`) and whether is not flagged hidden or system (`dir` without `/A` switch).

Answer (score 1):

The path to the package must come after the `/i`. Move the `/l*v` before the `/i` or after the path.